# Error on pthreads installation

Tags: php, pthreads

I'm trying to install the pThreads extension.

I did a compilation of php with this options:

```
brew install php71 --with-thread-safety --with-postgresql --with-homebrew-curl --enable-maintainer-zts
```

But the `--with-thread-safety` or `--enable-maintainer-zts` is not enough

> 1 warning and 14 errors generated.
>
> make: *** [php_pthreads.lo] Error 1
>
> ERROR: `make' failed

Witch step I fail?

Comment: How are you installing pthreads? And can you show more of the error? No stable release has been made for PHP 7.1 yet, so you'll have to use the master branch of [pthreads](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads) for now. Also, there's no need to use the `--enable-maintainer-zts` flag - the `--with-thread-safety` flag [results in the same command](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/commit/f1515c55777e6f149a51895ea6ef52fe81de55e0).